# Vmware Esxi 6.5 patching (upgrading specific VIBs from a patch bundle)

Tags: vmware, upgrade, esxi, patch

I have a couple of Esxi 6.5 hosts running a HPE custom image (build 6765664 May 2017).

I need to patch a vulnerability listed in VMSA-2015-0007.7.This requires that Esxi be patched with ESXi650-201806401-BG. The bulletin lists 4 VIBs that need to be updated to fix this vulnerability. However, when I download the patch file from the product patches site, the zip file contains many more VIBs than the 4 listed on the ESXi650-201806401-BG bulletin page.

So question is...Do I have to update all of the VIBs provided in this patch bundle or can I just install the 4 VIBs requred by the bulletin? We plan on uplifting the overall Esxi 6.5 build to 13004031 EP13 in the next few months but this needs to be properly tested for regression before we do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to update all of the VIBs provided in this patch bundle or can I just install the 4 VIBs required by the bulletin?

The archive file for ESXi650-201806001 contains fixes to 3 different bulletin numbers.

> 1. [ESXi650-201806001](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/55912)
> 2. [ESXi650-201806401-BG](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/55915)
> 3. [ESXi650-201806402-BG](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/55916)

The only files you need, in order to address [VMSA-2015-0007.7](https://www.vmware.com/security/advisories/VMSA-2015-0007.html) in question, are those associated with [VMware ESXi 6.5, Patch Release ESXi650-201806401-BG - Updates esx-base, esx-tboot, vsan, and vsanhealth VIBs (55915)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/55915).

1. VMware_bootbank_esx-base_6.5.0-2.54.8935087
2. VMware_bootbank_esx-tboot_6.5.0-2.54.8935087
3. VMware_bootbank_vsanhealth_6.5.0-2.54.8359237
4. VMware_bootbank_vsan_6.5.0-2.54.8359236

**This is confirmed by the table, on the page that indicates which knowlege article applies to each ESXi version, which points to ESXi650-201806401-BG instead of the other two knowlege articles which have files also contained with the file ESXi650-201806001.zip**

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. This is pretty much the original question I asked. I just wasn't sure if I had to update all the VIBs in the ESXi650-201806001.zip file or if I could just upgrade the 4 VIBs listed in the ESXi650-201806401-BG table. You've made that clear that I can update the individual VIBs, which I the info I needed. Thanks.

Comment: If your worried about the other 2 issues addressed by the other files, you might apply them, but they are not associated with the vulnerability you want to patch

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Ramhound. I was just worried as the esxi 6.5 build is currently version U1 and didn't know if updating these individual 4 VIBs to a later version would cause compatibility issues without updating the other VIBs contained in the overall patch file.